# From blob to image with struts2 and InputStream

Tags: jsp, struts2, inputstream

I would to know why I don't get anything with this. I have a function who return a byte array from SQL Server 2008 but I don't get anything, why? .getWhiteLabelingLogo() is a function which returns a byte[] with the image which I want to show at the jsp page. I access to this

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.axis.MessageContext;
import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;
import org.datacontract.schemas._2004._07.CCIS_Web_Services_PublicApi.PapiAccountInfo;
import org.datacontract.schemas._2004._07.CCIS_Web_Services_PublicApi.PapiUserInfo;

import Services.Web.CCIS.BasicHttpBinding_PublicApiServiceStub;
import Services.Web.CCIS.PublicApiService_PortType;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class ShowImageAction extends ActionSupport{
  Map session;
 private byte[] itemImage; 
 private InputStream str = null;
public String execute() throws RemoteException { 
    System.out.println("Estoy aquí");
        HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse(); 


   session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
   PublicApiService_PortType puerto=(PublicApiService_PortType) session.get("puerto");
   ((BasicHttpBinding_PublicApiServiceStub)puerto).setMaintainSession(true);

   MessageContext ctx=(MessageContext) session.get("contexto");
   PapiUserInfo[] users;

    users = puerto.getUsers();
    Long accountID=users[0].getID();
    PapiAccountInfo info=puerto.getAccountInfo(accountID);
            itemImage=info.getWhiteLabelingLogo();
            str=new ByteArrayInputStream(itemImage);
        return SUCCESS;




}

  public void setItemImage(byte[] itemImage) { 
      this.itemImage = itemImage; 
   }

   public InputStream getStr() {
    return str;
   }

   public void setStr(InputStream str) {
    this.str = str;
   }

   public byte[] getItemImage() {
    return itemImage;
   } 


  }
```

at index.jsp I have this:

```
<img src="<s:url value="ShowImageAction" />" border="0" width="100" height="100">
```

And in struts.xml I have this:

```
 <action name="ShowImageAction">
  <result name="success" type="stream">
    <param name="inputName">str</param>
    <param name="contentType">image/jpeg</param>

 </result>
</action>
```

What I'm doing bad because I haven't anything. Thanks so much

Comment: The source is difficult to read. Have you tried accessing the action directly? Have you verified the data from the DB? Have you checked the rendered HTML to make sure it's what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for starters, you don't have an action method at all. You *do* have a method named `execute`, but it is static and returns void. Action methods are non-static and return a String, which maps to a result in the struts.xml.

Additionally, after you set the content type on the response, you never send any data.

There are other problems with this action as well, such as the use of mutable static fields on the action, which is not thread-safe.

Here are some steps to take:

- Change the `execute` method to be non-static and return a String
- Add a `return SUCCESS;` line at the end of the method
- Update the struts.xml mapping to refer to the result "success" (SUCCESS is a constant for which the actual value is "success")
- Make the three member fields non-static
- Set the content type in the struts.xml, rather than in the code (see example below)
- Remove the response.reset() and .setContentType() calls

Example:

```
<action name="ShowImageAction" class="package.for.ShowImageAction">
  <result name="success" type="stream">
    <param name="contentType">image/jpeg</param>
    <param name="inputName">str</param>
  </result>
</action>
```

Then, if it is still not working for you, revise your question appropriately.

Comment: Hi Steven, first of all thanks, second....it doesn't work and I don't know why because I have follow all your steps

Comment: @zoit Revise your question then using the updated source code. Please take the time to format the source code too, so that it remains readable.

Comment: I have change everything now as you said to me and you can see on the top of this thread once again. Thanks so much

Comment: Try referencing the class name in your action mapping. Beyond that, are you getting an exception in your logs? Try setting a break point in your IDE when you run the application and see what is happening.